# Using 'convoy pattern' to obtain proof inside code of equality of pattern match

Tags: coq

It is a standard example of beginner's textbooks on category theory to argue that a preorder gives rise to a category (where the hom-set `hom(x,y)` is a singleton or empty depending on whether `x <= y`). When attempting to formalize this idea in coq, it is natural to view an arrow of as a triple `(x,y,pxy)` where `x y:A` (`A` being a type on which we have a preorder) and `pxy` is a proof that `x <= y`. So naturally, when attempting to define a composition of two arrows `(x,y,pxy)` and `(y',z,pyz)`, we need to return`Some` arrow whenever `y = y'` (or `None` otherwise). This implies that we are able to test for equality within the function, and compute a proof (the last field of our triple, which may rely on the fact that things are equal).

For the sake of this question, suppose I have:

```
Parameter eq_dec : forall {A:Type}, A -> A -> bool.
```

and:

```
Axiom eq_dec_correct : forall (A:Type) (x y:A),
    eq_dec x y = true -> x = y.  (* don't care about equivalence here *)
```

and let us assume I am attempting something simpler than defining composition between arrows, by writing a function which returns a proof that `x = y` whenever `x = y`.

```
Definition test {A:Type} (x y : A) : option (x = y) :=
    match eq_dec x y with
    | true     => Some (eq_dec_correct A x y _)
    | false    => None
    end.
```

This doesn't work of course, but probably gives you the idea of what I am trying to achieve. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Ok it seems this is a case of 'convoy pattern'. I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576238/extracting-evidence-of-equality-from-match) which suggested to me:

```
Definition test (A:Type) (x y:A) : option (x = y) :=
    match eq_dec x y as b return eq_dec x y = b -> option (x = y) with
    | true  => fun p => Some (eq_dec_correct A x y p)
    | false => fun _ => None
    end (eq_refl (eq_dec x y)).
```

This seems to be working. It is a bit magical and confusing but I'll get my head round it.

Comment: Isn’t composition in this case just the transitivity of p?

Comment: @JohnWiegley Yes it is. However, I am attempting to write a function which given two arrows `(x,y)` and `(y',z)` returns `Some` composed arrow or `None` (depending on whether `y=y'` or not). So within the body of my function, I need to check whether `y=y'` and I need to build a proof of `x <= z` (using transitivity). But while I pattern match on `eq_dec y y'` I need evidence that `y=y'` in order to use transitivity.

Comment: @SvenWilliamson I'm a bit confused... What is the question here? If you want to learn how the convoy pattern works, you can use SO's search: `[coq] convoy`. You'll find several examples and explanations and numerous references to Adam Chlipala's CPDT (to the MoreDep chapter). [Here](http://lpaste.net/360026) is a couple examples of how to implement `test`.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Thank you very much, yes it seems that my question was about the convoy pattern (or at least one application of it), although I did not know that when asking it. It was about having within your code a proof of the equality over which you are pattern matching.

Comment: The link you posted was actually extracted from a SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576238/extracting-evidence-of-equality-from-match.

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim Thank you Arthur, I have updated the link so as to point to the original.